# Having issues with my database? I am trying to have a section in my site where you can add a new neighborhood?

Tags: php, database, forms

I am trying to add a section in my site where you can fill out a small form and it will add the neighborhood in for you.  When I try to fill in the form and add the new neighborhood, I get the error below.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong and why I can't get these to be added into the database? Thanks for any help!

Code:

```
require_once('db.php');

//set the registration variables
$name = addslashes($_POST['name']);
$builder = addslashes($_POST['builder']);
$builderURL = $_POST['builderURL'];

//connect to database
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd);
if (!$link) {
    die(strip_tags('Could not connect: '.mysql_error()));
}

//add this contest to the database
$stmt = "INSERT INTO hf_neighborhoods (name, builder, builder_url, created_on) VALUES " .
        "('$name', '$builder', '$builderURL', NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($dbname, $stmt);
if(!$result){
    die(strip_tags('Error Adding Neighborhood: '.mysql_error()));
}

//if we made it this far, return a success
echo 'success';
?>

DB Call: 
<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'delsur_2011_dev';
$dbuser = 'delsur2011';
$dbpwd  = 'newsite!';

?>


Error:

<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in <b>/var/www/vhosts/delsurliving.com/httpdocs/hf/php/addNeighborhood.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
Error Adding Neighborhood:
```

---

```
Now I am receiving this error when I try to change it to that new code?  Is it just not connecting to the database at all now?  I am lost, I wasn't the one that set this file up, I was just told to go and try to fix it so that is what I am trying to do now? Thanks for your help
```

**Warning**:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in **/var/www/vhosts/delsurliving.com/httpdocs/hf/php/addNeighborhood.php** on line **8**
    
    **Warning**:  mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in **/var/www/vhosts/delsurliving.com/httpdocs/hf/php/addNeighborhood.php** on line **8**
    
    **Warning**:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in **/var/www/vhosts/delsurliving.com/httpdocs/hf/php/addNeighborhood.php** on line **9**
    
    **Warning**:  mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in **/var/www/vhosts/delsurliving.com/httpdocs/hf/php/addNeighborhood.php** on line **9**
    Error Adding Neighborhood: No database selected

Comment: make it a habit to use mysqli or PDO

Comment: Could you please update your code, too? you don't have any calls to `mysql_real_escape_string` in the code you've listed.

Comment: Modified my answer. You forgot to call mysql_select_db() too

Answer (score 2):

You have to change

```
$result = mysql_query($dbname, $stmt);
```

with

```
$result = mysql_query($stmt, $link);
```

However, using mysql_* functions is deprecated and its now considered a bad practice.

Instead you should be using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)!
And, dont use addslashes, at least use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

EDIT: You should be calling mysql_real_escape_String() after you connect to the database, and not before. And also, dont forget to call mysql_select_db()!

```
//connect to database
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd);
if (!$link) {
    die(strip_tags('Could not connect: '.mysql_error()));
}

mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);

// Sanitize your input at least!
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'], $link);
$builder = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['builder'], $link);
$builderUrl = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['builderUrl'], $link);

//add this contest to the database
$stmt = "INSERT INTO hf_neighborhoods (name, builder, builder_url, created_on) VALUES " .
    "('$name', '$builder', '$builderURL', NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($stmt, $link);
...
...
...
```

Comment: \Error Adding Neighborhood: No database selected

Comment: I am receiving that error now when I go in and do those changes? I didn't originally write this PHP someone else had and they just sent me in to go and fix it if I could so I am not sure why its not connecting to the database>

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: builderUrl in <b>/var/www/vhosts/delsurliving.com/httpdocs/hf/php/addNeighborhood.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
success

Comment: Still getting a small error, it says success but nothing is getting added into the db itself?  I am not sure?

Comment: Are you sure the $_POST variables are being sent?

Comment: <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once('db.php');

//set the registration variables
$name = addslashes($_POST['name']);
$builder = addslashes($_POST['builder']);
$builderURL = $_POST['builderURL'];

//connect to database
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd);
if (!$link) {
    die(strip_tags('Could not connect: '.mysql_error()));
}
mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);

Comment: // Sanitize your input 
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'], $link);
$builder = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['builder'], $link);
$builderUrl = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['builderUrl'], $link);

//add this contest to the database
$stmt = "INSERT INTO hf_neighborhoods (name, builder, builder_url, created_on) VALUES " .
    "('$name', '$builder', '$builderURL', NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($stmt, $link);
if(!$result){
 die(strip_tags('Error Adding Neighborhood: '.mysql_error()));
}

//if we made it this far, return a success
echo 'success';
?>

Comment: Here is the current code that is in place on that php page if that helps at all?

Comment: @SchellShockDesigns - you should probably mark this question as answered, and add the code in the above comments as a new question; you'll get a lot more people seeing your question, and are likely to get an answer faster. You should add the code, along with the message that you're getting from the database.